# Create table with columns of two fact tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two facts tables of SALES and ROYALTIES that are related via the following columns

- SALES[Store] = ROYALTIES[Store]
- SALES[Year] = ROYALTIES[Store]
- SALES[Category] = ROYALTIES[Store]

To avoid many-to-many relationships, I created 3 Tables with unique values for Store, Year, and Category that connect with a one-to-many relationship with the FactTables (as shown below)

[image]

The goal is to create a new table in DAX that reports.  
**[Store], [Year], [Category], [SalesAmount], [initial_value], [final_value], [royalties_pct]**

where:

- [Store], [Year], [Category] belong to both SALES and ROYALTIES tables.
- [SalesAmount] belongs to SALES
- [initial_value], [final_value], [royalties_pct] belong to ROYALTIES.

in SLQ would be:

```
SELECT s.store, s.year, s.category, SalesAmount, initial_value, final_value, royalties_pct
FROM sales as s
JOIN royalties as r
    ON s.store = r.store
    AND s.year = r.year
    AND s.category = r.category
```

How can I fix this in DAX to get the correct result?

Comment: Why [Store], [Category], [Year] on 2 different fact tables? What is the difference between them?

Comment: @OzanSen the [Store], [Category], [Year] columns of the two fact tables are of the same type, in fact they are used as foreign key

Comment: Please understand that There is no referential integrity concept in DAX. I know that you ensure this using foreign keys in SQL; but It seems to me that It is redundant. You need to improve your model!

Comment: What about making royalties table as dimension table with one * Many relationship to sales table ? Then SUMMARIZE() function can solve your problem!

Comment: `k_Store`, `k_Category` and `k_Year` are dims, not facts.

Comment: Why do you need to create this table in DAX? You have all the necessary data in your model, so you can calculate all this using measures with your dim tables setting up the necessary evaluation context.

Comment: @Marcus This is a thumbnail example for solving downstream queries using the row context of the calculated table

Comment: @OzanSen Simple and effective. I revised the model by adding in both tables a calculated column given by the concatenation of Store, Year, Category and linking with a one-to-many relationship SALES with ROYALTIES. Thanks

Comment: @pofferbacco Yeap, That's excellent strategy! You're welcome! Stay safe!